# What is causing the syntax error in my sql stored procedure?

Tags: mariadb

I'm pretty new at stored procedures and I get the following syntax error in my code:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //CREATE PROCEDURE sp_create_probe(IN matrix_id INT, IN oligo_id IN...' at line 2
```

Here's the code for my procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_create_probe(IN matrix_id INT, IN oligo_id INT)
BEGIN
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
  INSERT INTO Probes (oligo, microarray) VALUES (oligo_id, matrix_id);
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope someone can help me out

EDIT:
Well I ended up fixing it. Classic noob mistake.
I had this line before the code you see above:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_create_probe
```

Didn't copy that line into the post for some reason but it's missing the ";" at the end. That fixed it.

Comment: Get rid of the delimiter commands and replace `END //` with `END;`

Comment: Are you using Mariadb or Oracle (PL/SQL)?

Comment: @jarlh Doesn't the error message answer your question?

Comment: @JeffHolt Just tried it and still get pretty much the exact same error: 
```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE sp_create_probe(IN matrix_id INT, IN oligo_id INT)
BEGIN
  S...' at line 2```

Comment: @DennisWiersma Must be the tool you're using to execute the command. When I use the [mariadb dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b1c15baa6444b7ae3c10faaccfede9ea), I don't get any error.

Comment: @JeffHolt, rhetorical question due to conflicting dbms tags.

Comment: @JeffHolt I just tried manually entering the procedure into the database and it works just fine. But when I do `mariadb -D database_name < file.sql` in the terminal it still gives me the syntax error.